# How to tell the console which python to use for installation

Tags: python, terminal, installation, osx-snow-leopard, easy-install

normally I install site packages for python with `pip`. Unfortunately that does not work every time and I have to do it through the console. On OS X 10.6 is python 2.6 preinstalled, but I work with version 3.3 
How to I tell the console when typing `python setup.py install` to install it into my site-package folder of 3.3 AND, if i.e. easy install (distutils) is needed to look in my site-package folder of Version 3.3 for this site-package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the OS X `python` comes first in your path. Installing Python 3 should put a `python3` executable in your path. Use the following command.

```
python3 setup.py install
```

To ensure it installs in Python 3.3, and not another version of Python 3, use the following command.

```
python3.3 setup.py install
```

Alternatively, you could modify your `PATH` so that the Python 3 executable directory appears first in your path. Something like the following would work, if you adjust your path.

```
export PATH="/PATH/TO/PYTHON3/BINARY/:$PATH"
```

Comment: do I not need to specify which version? like 3.3?

Comment: @Christoph Did you try the `python3` command instead of `python`?

Comment: I`ll give it a go, takes a while. Big package. Looking at the terminal it looks like its installing it into 3.4, not 3.3

Comment: by the way. after running `setup.py install`do i always need to run `setup.py build`?

Comment: If you have more than one version of Python 3, you should use `python3.3`. See my updated answer.

Comment: that `python 3.3` worked. To update the `PATH`, should I not specify which version of python, i.e. `3.3`

Comment: If you want to update the path, you would need to point it to the exact version you want. Most-likely you don't need to update the PATH though.